# What software can visualise VTK file formats?

Tags: c++, vtk

I run a code which outputs many .vtk files. What software packages can I use to visualise these VTK files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check and see if [ParaView](http://www.paraview.org/) is what you are seeking. See [this wiki page](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/ParaView:FAQ#What_file_formats_does_ParaView_support.3F) for the specifics.

Answer (score 4):

I use visit. Have a look at the website: https://wci.llnl.gov/simulation/computer-codes/visit/

Comment: I don't recommend this. The so called Linux version comes without a single Readme file.